# Practical way to automate hourly releases on VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We would like to trigger two of our pipelines hourly. How can we do that other than this part as we want to implement **business rules such as do not run if there is an active deployment?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want hourly deployments, you'll need to create 24 schedules for each hour and then use the deployment queue setting. You can set the deployment queue settings to a max number of parallel deployments to 1.

For more information check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/environments)